# Share user authentication with different sites on same domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET MVC site that runs on www.company.com and has all the user registration and login pages etc.  I use Identity 2.0 for user management.

I would like to start migrating the site to an angular application with asp.net core web API on app.company.com

I'm not sure how to manage the user authentication / authorization.

The user would login to www.company.com, and parts of the site will (seamlessly to the user, aside from the URL change) go to app.company.com

How can I have a seamless sign on experience with app.company.com? app.company.com would need to know who the authenticated user is, even though that user authenticated against www.company.com?

Comment: [Single Sign On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)

Comment: Is SSO overly complicated considering the sites are in the same domain and can share a cookie?

Comment: From the linked Wiki: `A simple version of single sign-on can be achieved over IP networks using cookies but only if the sites share a common DNS parent domain.`

Comment: Typically, you could just share a cookie, as long as all sites are on the same domain (different subdomains are fine, as long as you set the cookie on the wildcard domain). However, cookie-based authentication is totally inappropriate for something like a web api. For that, you need to use something like a bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same situation in one of my project. Our solution was to use IdentityServer for SSO. You can configure IdentityServer to use your existing user database.